# UIView Zoomin Zoomout in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5

I have a view with  AF coverflowimages.When button(Zoomin) is clicked the image should Zoomin and when the zoomed image is clicked zoom out should take place.Can anyone help me out in writing the code for this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can scale your images using

> CGAffinTransformScale